# Can we create a single Power Automate flow which trigger when uploading documents inside 50 document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow, power-platform

We are planning to create a SharePoint online site and inside it we will create 50 document libraries. Now we need to have a single power automate flow which will trigger when uploading new documents inside the document libraries and send an email to a group which have the same name as the library.

So can we do so? or we will need to create 50 separate flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approaches for your requirements:

**A. Using Premium Connector**:

You can use HTTP action to trigger flow from multiple document libraries/lists in SharePoint.

Follow below articles for detailed steps:

1. [Deploying a single flow to multiple SharePoint libraries/lists](https://www.imenos.com/en/power-automate/deploying-a-single-flow-to-multiple-sharepoint-libraries-lists/)
2. [Trigger One Flow From Multiple SharePoint Lists](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/trigger-one-flow-from-multiple-sharepoint-lists/)
3. [One Flow to handle them all - how to subscribe to multiple SharePoint lists with one Flow](https://johnliu.net/blog/2019/3/one-flow-to-handle-them-all-how-to-subscribe-to-multiple-sharepoint-lists-with-one-flow)

**B. Using Parent-Child flows (Without Premium)**:

If you have common logic in Power automate flow for all document libraries, you can try this approach:

1. Create one parent flow for each document library using SharePoint connector trigger.
2. Create another (child) flow which will take inputs from parent flow and has common logic in flow.
3. Call child flow from parent flows.

By using this approach, you will have only one flow which executes the common operations. So, maintenance of flow will be easier in this case.

**Documentation**: [Create child flows - Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)

Comment: so in this case i still need to create 50 parent flows and one child flow which contain the logic am i correct?

Comment: Yes correct. But good thing is all the logic will be in single child flow and easily maintainable. Parent flow will only have trigger and action to call child flow.