# How to save "Site Address" and "List Name" to variable and use it in power automate .I want multiple list to use one power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

I have several lists with the same fields names. I'm working on a flow that I need to re-use.

I want to be able to pass the site name and the list name dynamically to the flow.

So basically I would like to use same flow for all my lists. Is this possible?

Comment: Will this be a automated flow or manually triggered flow? check my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/can-we-create-a-single-power-automate-flow-which-trigger-when-uploading-document/304341#304341. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.This would be automated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the variables for SharePoint site address/URL and list names.

While using variables, you have to pass values to SharePoint connector actions using "Enter custom value" option.

**Example**:

Flow:

[image]

Action:

[image]

You can also consider using approaches mentioned here for using single Power automate flow for multiple SharePoint lists: [Can we create a single Power Automate flow which trigger when uploading documents inside 50 document libraries](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/can-we-create-a-single-power-automate-flow-which-trigger-when-uploading-document/304341#304341)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.The question is how can I automatically pass the site address and list name from the list view when I need to trigger the flow

Comment: Which trigger are you trying to use in your flow?

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
I use "when an item or a file is modified."
Thanks

Comment: Check link in my answer, you can create a single flow for each list where you can select site address and list name from flow editor and use child flow for reusable operations/actions. Call child flow from main flow on each list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. E.g. if you want to use action Get items, you have to use two variables. In the **first variable** you have to store **site URL** (in format https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/teams/siteName) and in the **second** you have store **list GUID** (from list properties). Then in the first choice of the Get items action (Site Address) select **Enter custom value** and insert first variable with URL. In the second choice (List Name) select **Enter custom value** as well and insert second variable with list GUID (really not list name, but list GUID).
Then when Flow runs it retrieves items from that list with corresponding URL and GUID. But be aware that in the next steps **you cannot use columns from this action directly**, because when you are creating your Flow, the designer does not know from which list you will be retrieving your data. So it cannot offer you right list schema. You have to use something like **@{outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']}**.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bug some times, you can solve it easyly.
Add your url manually, "enter custom value"
[image]
then even if the message appear add the id of the list, save your flow and it will work

get the id in your list when you navigate in your list setting

SKIP %7B and %7D
[image]

[image]

Save and it should be ok

The list ID should be replaced by the correct list title

[image]

http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/power-plateform/powerautomateweareunabletofindthesiteaddress.html